# Can't find the javascript code for Twitter signup form variable signup_ui_metrics

Tags: javascript, twitter

I try to find the javascript that generates the form post variable **signup_ui_metrics** at https://twitter.com/signup

When I try to register without javascript the varible is empty. When I activate jascript it gets filled like this:

```
signup_ui_metrics = {
    "tt": 32387,
    "v": 2,
    "gts": 1438124809690,
    "h": "49678c77",
    "b": "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"
}
```

I already found out that the "gts":1438124809690 variable is from:

```
<div id="ui_metrics" class="ui-metrics-seed">**1438124809690**</div>
```

**"v":2** is always the same.

But have no idea how the other variables are generated. anybody have an idea?
Thanks for help :)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

tt is the time in milliseconds that it takes to fill out the registration form. You dont have to actually wait this time, just specify this number. This number is also used when generating the h variable. v can be 1, instead of 2, and this way you dont have to generate b. But for registering you need v as 2, so you need b. I still haven't found out how to generate b yet. If I do, Ill give you some tips.

I just did some more research. There is a .js file that is referenced in the signup page which contains the ui_metrics function which is **obfuscated**. If you deobfuscate it you see it uses the GuestID value from the cookie with the same name, the username you want to register, and the time it took to fill out the registration form in milliseconds. Then using bitwise operators it generates the h-hash, which is then used in another algorithm to generate the b-hash.